# extjs spinner _ on mouse cilck the alert is coming behind the window

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs3

I am facing a problem with extjs-spinner.

I 've two spinners(minlength, maxlength) in my application.

If minlength greater than maxlength or if maxlength less than minlength I need to raise an alert.

If I am increasing the spinner value using up and down arrow keys in board alert is comming on the window. This is fine.

But If I am increasing the spinner value using mouse, the alert is comming behind the window where the alert is not visible and I am unable close the alert until I close the parent window.

The spinners are looks like this image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r5V8.png)

My organization developed its own framework which uses extjs. The event handler code for spinner is as follows

```
 cbx.formElement.SpinnerField = function(config){
    this.plainLabel = config.plainLbl;
    this.fieldLabel = config.displayNmKey;
    this.name = config.itemId;
    //CHG_MULTIFORM Starts
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(config.multiInd) && config.multiInd==true && !Ext.isEmpty(config.index)){
        this.value = config.model.getModelData()[config.multiFormId][config.itemId][config.index];
    }else{
        this.value = config.model.getModelData()[config.itemId];    
    }
    //CHG_MULTIFORM Ends
    this.required = config.requiredInd;
    this.conditional = config.conditionalInd;
    this.readOnly = config.readOnlyInd === 'Y' ? true : false;
    this.hidden = config.visibleInd === 'Y' ? false : true;
    this.validationType = config.vType;
    /**
     * Below code commented so that the developer can provide minimum value in
     * cbxpreinitialize event else the default minimum value 0 will be assigned
     */
    // this.minValue='0'; //CBX_FW_Q112F_106
    cbx.formElement.SpinnerField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};

Ext.extend(cbx.formElement.SpinnerField, Ext.ux.form.SpinnerField, {
    required : 'N',
    conditional : 'N',
    bundleKey : '',
    minValue:0, // CBX_FW_Q112F_106
    lookup : false,
    vtype :'invalidChars',
    allowDecimals: false, // CBX_165
    incrementValue: 1,
    accelerate: 'true',
    labelSeparator:'',
     validationType : 'numeric', // CBX_FW_Q112F_106
   // allowSpaces : false,
   plainLabel : '',
    fieldLabel : '',
    // cls : 'x-form-textField',
     // private
    initComponent:function(){
        //CBXFW_DIT_77 starts
        this.on('hide',Ext.createDelegate(this.updateVisibilityInSV, this, [this,'N']));
        this.on('show',Ext.createDelegate(this.updateVisibilityInSV, this, [this,'Y']));
        //CBXFW_DIT_77 ends
        if (Ext.isEmpty(this.maxLength)) {
            this.maxLength = undefined;
        }
        if (Ext.isEmpty(this.minLength)) {
            this.minLength = undefined;
        }
        cbx.formElement.SpinnerField.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);   
        var bundle;
        var commonbundle = CRB.getFWBundle();
        bundle = CRB.getBundle(cbx.jsutil.getBundleKey(this));
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(this.plainLabel)) {
            this.fieldLabel = this.plainLabel;
        } else if (Ext.isEmpty(this.fieldLabel)) {
            this.fieldLabel = '';
        } else {
            this.fieldLabel = bundle['LBL_' + this.fieldLabel];
        }
        if (this.maxLength < Number.MAX_VALUE) {
            this.maxLengthText = String.format(
                    commonbundle['ERR_MAXLENGTH_EXCEED'],
                    this.fieldLabel, this.maxLength);
        }
        if (this.minLength < Number.MIN_VALUE) {
            this.minLengthText = String.format(
                    commonbundle['ERR_MINLENGTH_EXCEED'],
                    this.fieldLabel, this.minLength);
        }
        if (this.conditional === 'Y') {
            this.blankText = String.format(
                    commonbundle['ERR_MANDATORY'], this.fieldLabel);
            if (Ext.isEmpty(this.fieldLabel)) {
                this.fieldLabel = '?' + this.fieldLabel + '?'
                        + '<span class = \'cbx-mandatory-fx\'">**</span>';// CHG001-CSS
                                                                            // changes
            } else {
                this.fieldLabel = this.fieldLabel
                        + '<span class = \'cbx-mandatory-fx\'">**</span>';// CHG001-CSS
            }
        }
        else if (this.required === 'Y') {
            this.allowBlank=false;  
            this.blankText = String.format(
                    commonbundle['ERR_MANDATORY'], this.fieldLabel);
            if (Ext.isEmpty(this.fieldLabel)) {
                this.fieldLabel = '?' + this.fieldLabel + '?'
                        + '<span class = \'mandatory\'">*</span>';
            } else {
                this.fieldLabel = this.fieldLabel
                        + '<span class = \'mandatory\'">*</span>';
            }
        } else {
            this.blankText = String.format(
                    commonbundle['ERR_MANDATORY'], this.fieldLabel);
            if (Ext.isEmpty(this.fieldLabel)) {
                this.fieldLabel = '?' + this.fieldLabel + '?'
                        + '<span class = \'non_mandatory\'"></span>';
            } else {
                this.fieldLabel = this.fieldLabel
                        + '<span class = \'non_mandatory\'"></span>';
            }
        }
        this.labelSeparator = '';
    this.onBlur=function(){ console.log("test spin onBlur");//nageswara
    this.clearInvalid();  // CBX_FW_Q112F_106
    this.validate();      // CBX_FW_Q112F_106
    this.syncModelData();
    this.spinnerMandatoryValidator(this.getValue());
    };
    this.on('spin',function(obj){
        console.log("test spin on"); // nageswara
        this.clearInvalid(); // CBX_FW_Q112F_106
        this.syncModelData();
        this.spinnerMandatoryValidator(obj.value);
        });
        switch(this.validationType) {
            case 'alphaNumeric' : 
                            if(this.allowSpaces){
                                this.maskRe = /[A-Za-z0-9 ]/;
                            }else{
                            this.maskRe = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
                            }
                            break;
            case 'numeric' : 
                            if(this.allowSpaces){
                            this.maskRe = /[0-9 ]/;
                            }else{
                            this.maskRe = /[0-9]/;
                            }
                            break;
            case 'portalSupported' : 
                            if(this.allowSpaces){
                            this.maskRe = /[^<>;{}()!=&\'\"]/;
                            }else{
                            this.maskRe = /[0-9]/;
                            }
                            break;                              
        }
        this.anchor = (this.anchor == undefined) ? '' : this.anchor ;
    },
 afterRender:function(){
     var that=this;
     this.updateScreenViewData(this);//CBXFW_DIT_77
     cbx.formElement.SpinnerField.superclass.afterRender
        .call(this); 
     this.getEl().on('keyup',function(){  
         console.log("tes keyup"); // nageswara
            that.clearInvalid();
            });
        if(this.copyPasteInd==="Y")
            {
     this.getEl().on('keydown',preventCopyPaste,this);
     this.getEl().on('drop',preventCopyPaste,this);
     this.getEl().on('dragstart',preventCopyPaste,this);
     this.getEl().on('draggesture',preventCopyPaste,this);
            }
 },
syncModelData : function() {
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(this.multiInd) && this.multiInd==true && !Ext.isEmpty(this.multiFormId)){
        this.model.updateValue(this.name, this.getValue(),undefined,this.index,this.multiFormId);   
    }else{
        this.value = this.model.getModelData()[this.name];////CT1.0_FFW Fixes
        this.model.updateValue(this.name, this.getValue());
    }
        this.updateScreenViewData(this);//CBXFW_DIT_77
},
setMinValue: function(minValue) {
 if(!Ext.isEmpty(minValue) && !(isNaN(minValue))){
     this.minValue=minValue;
 }
},
setMaxValue: function(maxValue) {
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(maxValue) && !(isNaN(maxValue))){
         this.maxValue=maxValue;
     }
},
setdefaultValue: function(defaultValue) {
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(defaultValue) && !(isNaN(defaultValue))){
         this.defaultValue=defaultValue;
     }
},
setDecimalPrecision: function(allowDecimalPrecision) { 
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(allowDecimalPrecision) ){
        if(this.allowDecimals==true && !(isNaN(allowDecimalPrecision))){
            this.decimalPrecision=allowDecimalPrecision;
        }
     }
},
validate:function(){
    if (!this.disabled && (this.el.dom.className.indexOf('errorBg')!=-1 || this.el.dom.className.indexOf(this.invalidClass) != -1)) {
    return false;
    }
    if(this.disabled || this.validateValue(this.processValue(this.getRawValue()))){
               this.clearInvalid();
               return true;
           }
           return false;
    },
    isVisible : function(){
        return cbx.formElement.SpinnerField.superclass.isVisible.apply(this, arguments);  
    },
    getPrintData : function(){
        var label = this.plainLabel;
        var fieldValue = this.getValue();
        var printMap = {};
        printMap[label] = fieldValue;
        return printMap;
    },
    spinnerMandatoryValidator : function(v){
        // TODO bundle to be changed. This should be common bundle
        combundle = CRB.getFWBundle();
        if(combundle !== null){
            if((v == '') && (this.required==='Y')){
                this.markInvalid(this.blankText);               
            }
        }
        else {          
                if((v == '') && (this.required==='Y')){
                this.markInvalid('? ERR_MANDATORY ?');
            }
        }
    },
    getScreenViewData:function()
    {
        return this.getValue();
    }
});
```

The below code is about how the minlength, maxlength alerts are developed....

```
    this.fm.registerHandler("cbxchange", "MAX_LENGTH", function(fm,event,fieldName,value){
        var MaxLength = parseInt(fm.model.getValue("MAX_LENGTH"));
        var MinLength = parseInt(fm.model.getValue("MIN_LENGTH"));
        MaxLength = parseInt(MaxLength);
        MinLength = parseInt(MinLength);
        if(MaxLength < MinLength){
            var err_Dialog = new iportal.Dialog({
                  dialogType : 'MESSAGE',
                  title : 'Validation',
                  message : 'MaxLength Always Greater Than MinLength', // WDK_FORMFW_CLEANUP
                  okHandler : function (){
                      err_Dialog.close();
                  }
              });
              err_Dialog.show();
              fm.clearValues(['MAX_LENGTH']);
        }
    });
    this.fm.registerHandler("cbxchange", "MIN_LENGTH", function(fm,event,fieldName,value){
        var MaxLength = parseInt(fm.model.getValue("MAX_LENGTH"));
        var MinLength = parseInt(fm.model.getValue("MIN_LENGTH"));
        if( MinLength > MaxLength && MaxLength!=NaN){
            var err_Dialog = new iportal.Dialog({
                  dialogType : 'MESSAGE',
                  title : 'Validation',
                  message : 'MinLength Should Not Exceed Than MaxLength', // WDK_FORMFW_CLEANUP
                  okHandler : function (){
                      err_Dialog.close();
                  }
              });
              err_Dialog.show();
              fm.clearValues(['MIN_LENGTH']);
        }
    });
```

Comment: if minlength>maxlength or maxlength<minlength , the alert is comming. but its coming twice,  - I am unable to find why its coming twice.

Answer (score 1):

1. For alert is coming behind the window:
   You can manage it by following steps:

   - a. if `minlength > maxlength` or `maxlength < minlength`, check `z-index` value of the window and do +1 in it.
   - b. create your err_Dialog and
     apply increased `z-index` in err_Dialog's style.
2. For the alert is coming twice:
   You can provide `id` in your err_Dialog like below:

   `var err_Dialog = new iportal.Dialog({
          id: 'my_err_dialog',
          dialogType : 'MESSAGE',
          title : 'Validation',
          message : 'MinLength Should Not Exceed Than MaxLength', // WDK_FORMFW_CLEANUP
          okHandler : function (){
              err_Dialog.close();
          }
      });`

   and then,
   if `minlength > maxlength` or `maxlength < minlength` and you want to display alert, add the below code:

   `if(Ext.getCmp('my_err_dialog')) {
         Ext.getCmp('my_err_dialog').close();
      }`

   after this add the below code to display the alert:

   `var err_Dialog = new iportal.Dialog({
          id: 'my_err_dialog',
          dialogType : 'MESSAGE',
          title : 'Validation',
          message : 'MinLength Should Not Exceed Than MaxLength', // WDK_FORMFW_CLEANUP
          okHandler : function (){
              err_Dialog.close();
          }
      }); 
      err_Dialog.show();`

Hope this help :)